# How do I change the signature in Gmail depending on who the message is to?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

For personal messages I just end messages with my name but for business it would be nice to have a signature that had my name and phone number and all that.

I know about "canned responses" and I've set that up, but it would be nice if I there were fewer clicks to get to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an alternate email address to send messages to the different targets (an email for your friends and another one for business). Then, in the signature settings you can specify which signature to use when sending emails from each address.

Then when sending an email, just choose the email depending on the receiver(s) and Gmail will automatically use the right signature.

Otherwise you're stuck with the canned responses feature.